# Add to integers in a list

Tags: python, list, integer, addition

I have a list of integers and I was wondering if it would be possible to add to individual integers in this list.

Comment: What do you mean by "add to individual integers" - would you like to add the same number to a given set of elements, say element 1, 5, 10, and 23?

Comment: Not enough information to answer the question. What does "add to individual integers in this list" mean?

Comment: Please show an example of what you want the list to look like before and after the operation.

Comment: By adding to individual integgers I meant I wanted the list to go in as [0,0,0,0] and come out as [0,1,1,0] where you can choose what is being added to what integer in what position

Comment: What's amazing is that this question, as written, has three up votes. What's more amazing is the quality of the answers.

Comment: This question is completely incomprehensible.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is an example where the things to add come from a dictionary

```
>>> L = [0, 0, 0, 0]
>>> things_to_add = ({'idx':1, 'amount': 1}, {'idx': 2, 'amount': 1})
>>> for item in things_to_add:
...     L[item['idx']] += item['amount']
... 
>>> L
[0, 1, 1, 0]
```

Here is an example adding elements from another list

```
>>> L = [0, 0, 0, 0]
>>> things_to_add = [0, 1, 1, 0]
>>> for idx, amount in enumerate(things_to_add):
...     L[idx] += amount
... 
>>> L
[0, 1, 1, 0]
```

You could also achieve the above with a list comprehension and zip

```
L[:] = [sum(i) for i in zip(L, things_to_add)]
```

Here is an example adding from a list of tuples

```
>>> things_to_add = [(1, 1), (2, 1)]
>>> for idx, amount in things_to_add:
...     L[idx] += amount
... 
>>> L
[0, 1, 1, 0]
```

Comment: @user12379095, I don't think that is related to this question. Can you post a new question and include your code?

Answer (score 20):

You can append to the end of a list:

```
foo = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
foo.append(4)
foo.append([8,7])    
print(foo)            # [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, [8, 7]]
```

You can edit items in the list like this:

```
foo = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
foo[3] = foo[3] + 4     
print(foo)            # [1, 2, 3, 8, 5]
```

Insert integers into the middle of a list:

```
x = [2, 5, 10]
x.insert(2, 77)
print(x)              # [2, 5, 77, 10]
```

Comment: this will give this kind of error`IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
`

Answer (score 5):

```
fooList = [1,3,348,2]
fooList.append(3)
fooList.append(2734)
print(fooList) # [1,3,348,2,3,2734]
```

Answer (score 2):

If you try appending the number like, say
`listName.append(4)` ,  this will append `4` at last.
But if you are trying to take `<int>` and then append it as, `num = 4` followed by `listName.append(num)`, this will give you an error as `'num' is of <int> type` and `listName is of type <list>`. So do type cast `int(num)` before appending it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible since lists are mutable.

Look at the built-in [`enumerate()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#enumerate) function to get an idea how to iterate over the list and find each entry's index (which you can then use to assign to the specific list item).